# Excel query - check duplicates in two columns and return outcome

Tags: excel, duplicates

[[image: excel example of duplicates]

Hi - I am trying to find duplicates in column A, if there is a duplicate in column A check column B is the same and if not return a field in column C.

Example in image - A2 to A4 are the same and so is B2 to B4 therefore no action required. A5 to A8 are the same but B5 to B8 are different so they need to be checked.

I believe the correct formula is a combination of `IF` and `COUNTIFS` but I can’t quite get it right. I can find the duplicates easily in column A or B but can’t get the co-dependency right I think I am missing something in the middle

`=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2, B:B, B2)>1), “no action”, “check”)`

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 open brackets and 3 close brackets in the formula . Otherwise its working for me.